# Como llamar el sweetalert2 en un @if(session('status1')) que esta en html?

Tags: laravel, script, sweetalert2

necesito ayuda con sweetalert2, tengo una validación en el controllador el cual me retorna con un `with('statusX')` y necesito que dependiendo del return me envie un sweetalert

intente llamar el sweetalert con `target: document.getElementById('status1')`

Return en el controlador

```
`
   return redirect()->back()->with('status1');

   return redirect()->back()->with('status2');

`
```

HTML

`@if(session('status1'))
  <div id="status1"></div>
@endif`

`@if(session('status2'))
  <div id="status2"></div>
@endif`

Sweetalert2

`<script>
    Swal.fire({
      type: 'success',
      title: 'Tu evento ha sido añadido!',
      showConfirmButton: true,
      target: document.getElementById('status1')
    })
</script>`

Necesito que al momento de que la validación sea correcta, me aparezca la alerta correspondiente de sweetalert2.

actualmente al apretar el botón guardar de mi formulario sea cual sea la validación se abre la alerta, también al recargar la pagina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo uso sweetalert de esta forma, en tu controlador puedes retornar de la siguiente forma

```
return redirect()->back()->with($message);
```

Donde la variable `$message` seria asi

```
$message = array(
    'message' => 'Exito',
    'type'    => 'success'
);
```

En tu archivo `blade.php` puedes usar una sintaxis como esta para seleccionar el tipo de alerta que quieres

```
@if (Session::has('message'))
    var type = "{{ Session::get('type') }}";

    const toast = swal.mixin({
        toast: true,
        position: 'top-end',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 5000
    });

    switch(type){
        case 'info':
            toast({
                    type: 'info',
                    title: "{{ Session::get('message') }}"
                })
        break;

        case 'warning':
            toast({
                type: 'warning',
                title: "{{ Session::get('message') }}"
            })
        break;

        case 'success':
            toast({
                type: 'success',
                title: "{{ Session::get('message') }}"
            })
        break;

        case 'error':
           toast({
                type: 'error',
                title: "{{ Session::get('message') }}"
            })
        break;
    }
@endif
```

Esto verificara si existe la variable `message` y ya tiene los 2 parametros necesarios, `type` y `message`, solo tienes que personalizar la alerta que quieras usar de la libreria, en este caso estoy usando los `toast`

Comment: Muchas gracias!, intente utilizar asi tal cual me compartiste el codigo, pero no se muestra la alerta y en la consola de google chrome indica un error 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
    at o (sweetalert2.all.min.js:1)
    at e (sweetalert2.all.min.js:1)
    at calendario:417`

y hace referencia al `toast`

Comment: Recuerda que tienes que adaptar el codigo al tipo de alerta que estas usando de la libreria, te hace referencia al toast por que en este ejemplo yo uso ese tipo de alertas, tu tienes que reemplazar todos los toast por el que tu necesitas

Comment: Vale, ya me funciono, Muchas gracias!!